# Many worlds is nonlocal too after all according to some physicists?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations, locality, non-locality

Not a physicist but I have understood that MWI is unique in that it preserves local dynamics. There is a wavefunction - not in spacetime but in some more abstract space. But the worlds with spacetime were local.

The wikipedia article on QM interpretations says the same: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpretations_of_quantum_mechanics#Comparisons

But Tim Maudlin and it seems Lev Vaidman (and one other I don't know) say MWI is no longer thought to be a local theory (in the sense of Bell at least). https://youtu.be/2IpUBCjzq3E?t=2810 (~1:10 clip) and https://youtu.be/2IpUBCjzq3E?t=3825 (15 second clip) They don't get a chance to expound any further here.

What changed?

Edit: added some more details

Answer (score 1):

I don't think anything has changed, and they don't seem to claim that anything has changed. There was just never a consensus on whether MWI is "local", whatever than means.

Everyone agrees that you can't build a faster-than-light radio in MWI (if the underlying physics is Lorentz invariant), so it's local in that sense. Everyone also agrees that Bell's inequality is violated in MWI, which means that it's not local in the sense that's assumed when proving Bell's inequality (which is hard to pin down).

Most rivals of MWI share those properties. Claims that MWI is more local than alternatives boil down to the idea that, because MWI doesn't "commit" to a particular measurement outcome, it doesn't need to choose the outcomes of the Bell/EPR measurements at the spacelike separated locations where they happen. The results need to be consistent with quantum mechanics when compared to each other, but to be compared they have to be brought to the same location, and any interaction between them that needs to happen happens then. There is certainly a sense in which that's true, but it's hard to say whether it means that MWI is local. It's just difficult to say what "local" ought to mean, beyond the operational definition (can't build a FTL radio) which is uncontroversially satisfied by MWI.

Comment: Thanks -  Can we say there are at least two kinds of nonlocality then? The nonlocality within spacetime like pilot-wave theory vs. the collapse or splitting of the wavefunction in abstract space like Copenhagen or MWI? And why does Maudin say "there was a thought that MWI would be a local theory" (2nd clip)?